# DB2 list of all locked tables

Tags: db2, locking, zos

What is the query or the table with which I can easily view all the list of Db2 zos tables which are locked ? In oracle we can view all tables and check the table status similarly in dB2, how can we get the list of locked tables

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DISPLAY DATABASE (LOCKS)`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=commands-display-database-db2) command.

Comment: When am writing DISPAY DATABASE (XXxX) SPACENAM(YYYYY) USE LIMIT(*); then am getting the following errors like DISPLAY is unknown,